# If $x^3+ax^2=bx+c$ (with $a,b,c>0$) has one positive root and two negative roots, then what can you say about the roots of $x^3+c=ax^2+bx$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

I can't manage to solve this maths problem. I was hoping someone could answer it and explain how they did it to me. Bear in mind I have only just finished A levels so I wont understand any crazy business/shenanigans any of you maths graduates might get up to. However, I don't think any of that will be necessary to answer this question.

> The positive real numbers a, b and c are such that the equation
>
> $$x^3 + ax^2 = bx + c$$
>
> has three real roots, one positive and two negative.
>
> Which one of the following correctly describes the real roots of the equation
>
> $$x^3 + c = ax^2 + bx$$
>
> A. It has three real roots, one positive and two negative.
>
> B. It has three real roots, two positive and one negative.
>
> C. It has three real roots, but their signs differ depending on $a$, $b$, and $c$.
>
> D. It has exactly one real root, which is positive.
>
> E. It has exactly one real root, which is negative.
>
> F. It has exactly one real root, whose sign differs depending on $a$, $b$, and $c$.
>
> G. The number of real roots can be one or three, but the number of roots differs depending on $a$, $b$, and ܿ$c$.

You can find the question written more nicely [in this PDF](https://www.admissionstesting.org/Images/314864-test-of-mathematics-for-university-admission-specimen-paper-paper-2.pdf) (Question 19):

Comment: In this forum, you should include your own attempts to solve the problem, before you can expect us to solve it.  What do you know about "number of roots" of a polynomial equation?  For example, do you know Descartes' Rule of Signs?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! Could you tell us more about the context of your problem. Other MSE users need this information to understand what you already know and what has to be explained in the answer.

Comment: @ GEdgar, I dont really have any attempts as I couldnt come up with any

Comment: @ Yanior Weg, What do you want to know, all I want is a solution

Comment: Hint: The second equation can be rewritten as$$\begin{align} x^3 + c = ax^2 + bx \iff & x^3 - a x^2 - bx + c = 0\\
\iff & -(-x)^3 - a(-x)^2 + b(-x) + c = 0\\
\iff & (-x)^3 + a(-x)^2 = b(-x) + c\end{align}$$
If you compare last expression with your first equation, ...

Comment: sorry I struggled to understand achille

Comment: @achille hui, oooh I think I understand. Is what your saying that the second equation is just (-x) subbed in for x so the graph is just reflected in the y axis?

Comment: Yup. the roots of 2nd equation is just the negative of the roots of 1st equation.

Comment: I find the test referenced contain good practice. Is it possible to share the answers with me? It is OK if you can't. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm not particularly great but If there is any questions I get that you don't then thats no problem. It would also be pretty helpful if I could ask you any questions too, do you have facebook or something else that we could discuss questions on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [Rule of Signs](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-rule-signs.html).

It says that:

> The number of sign changes is the maximum number of positive roots

Your 2nd equation, after re-ordering the powers of $x$ can be written as:

$$+x^3 -a x^2 - bx  - c$$

The sign changes between the first 2 terms is 1 (changed from + to - one time).

The sign change between the 2nd term and the 3rd term is zero (we have -a, -b).

The sign change between the 3rd term and the 4th term is zero (we have -b, -c).

Total number of sign changes is: $1+0+0=1$.

This tells us that this polynomial has at most $1$ POSITIVE real root (EDITED).

This makes choices A, C, D, E ,F False.

G is false because a polynomial of degree $n$ will always have $n$ roots and does not depend on $a,b,c$.

To make that sure that the real root is negative using the same rule, change every $(x)$ to $(-x)$ .

$$f(-x)=-1.x^3+ax^2+bx-c$$

Now counting the number of sign changes we get:

From (-1 to +a) = 1 change in sign

From (+a to +b) = 0 change in sign

From (+b to -c)= 1 change in sign

Total sign changes for $f(-x)=1+0+1=2$

This indicates that we have at most 2 NEGATIVE real roots (or zero negative roots if these 2 remaining roots are complex, since complex roots always come in pairs).

**To summarize**

We either have 2 negative roots or 0 negative roots AND we have at most 1 real positive roots.

This leaves B as the answer closest to correctness as you have noticed.

Comment: "Since a,b,c are all positive, a root, which makes the equation zero, can't be the sum of positive numbers. In fact no root could be positive real root under these conditions." Sorry I didnt understand this part

Comment: OK, take the a simpler example. $y=4x+1$. At what value of $x$, $y=0$?. The answer is $-0.25$. In this case $4,1$ are positive, how could we ever find a positive value of $x$ that could make $y$=0? We can't. We need to multiply $4$ by a negative value so that when we add it to $1$, we get y=0. In summary when all the coefficients are positive and the degree of the polynomial is odd (1,3,...etc.) the root must be negative. As an additional example look at the case at the bottom of the answer. I will be happy to discuss it more.

Comment: oh ok, I see what you mean, but the equation: +x3−ax2−bx−c is not all negative as the coefficient of the x^3 is positive

Comment: Phrase removed. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: oooh ok I think I realised how to get the answer now, I think it is just that the second equation is the first equation with (-x) subbed in for x, therefore the second equation is just a reflection of the first equation in the y axis. that means if the first equation has one positive root and two negative, the second has two positive one negative as it is just reflected. I think that might have been what the guy in the comments was saying but unfortunately for him, he didnt make it an answer so I cant give him credit. In that case, that makes your answer best answer

Comment: The answer was B which you have ruled out but I think I know why. Im only just hearing of the rule of signs but is it not that the number of sign changes gives the maximum number of positive roots where as you have said real roots

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have edited the answer. The rule tells us "at most 1 positive roots" and when we switch (x) to (-x), the number of sign changes indicate the maximum number of negative roots if any. I was not aware of the role of the first equation at all and I did not grasp the answer in the comment, as it was so brief for me to get. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Odd degree polynomials with real coefficients have at least one real root.  Complex solutions come in conjugate pairs.  Use those theorems.

Comment: ok thanksmmmmmmmmmmmmmm